# plot dashline using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to know how to plot the dashlines in this graph. I mean the gray dashlines which are related to the points.

[image]

Comment: Which terminal are you using?  You can usually enable dashed lines by adding the `dashed` option to the `set terminal ___` command, then see which linetypes are available with the `test` command.

Comment: What grey dashed lines are you talking about?  Are you referring to the grid?  In that case `set grid` should do the trick.